# How to resolve the Flume Syslog set up error - "Event size larger than specified event size: 2500. Consider increasing the max event size"

Tags: flume

I am trying to set up Flume syslog source using `org.apache.flume.source.MultiportSyslogTCPSource`. Set up and configuration successful but I get the following error while flume generates the event from syslog.

```
[INFO ] [2019-03-28 13:22:27.217] [[channel=file-channel] - CheckpointBackUpThread] [org.apache.flume.channel.file.EventQueueBackingStoreFile] - Checkpoint backup completed.

[WARN ] [2019-03-28 13:22:31.853] [NioProcessor-2] 

[org.apache.flume.source.MultiportSyslogTCPSource] - Event size larger than specified event size: 2500. Consider increasing the max event size.
    [INFO ] [2019-03-28 13:22:35.686] [SinkRunner-PollingRunner-DefaultSinkProcessor] [org.apache.flume.sink.LoggerSink] - Event: { headers:{flume.syslog.status=Invalid} body: 31 33 33 62 32 20 74 3C 31 33 34 3E 4D 61 72 20 133b2 t<134>Mar  }
```

Here is my configuration looks like:

```
#source,channel and sink
testagent.sources = testlog
testagent.channels = file-channel
testagent.sinks = logger-sink

#source
testagent.sources.testlog.type = org.apache.flume.source.MultiportSyslogTCPSource
testagent.sources.testlog.ports = 9002
testagent.sources.testlog.host = 127.0.0.1

#sink
testagent.sinks.logger-sink.type = logger

#channel
testagent.channels.file-channel.type = file
testagent.channels.file-channel.dataDirs = /test/data/01/
testagent.channels.file-channel.checkpointDir = /test/data/01/checkpoint
testagent.channels.file-channel.useDualCheckpoints = true
testagent.channels.file-channel.backupCheckpointDir = /test/data/01/checkpoint-backup
testagent.channels.file-channel.transactionCapacity = 10000
testagent.channels.file-channel.checkpointInterval = 20000
testagent.channels.file-channel.maxFileSize = 1072692224
testagent.channels.file-channel.minimumRequiredSpace = 524288000
testagent.channels.file-channel.capacity = 1000000
testagent.channels.file-channel.keep-alive = 3
testagent.channels.file-channel.checkpointOnClose = true
testagent.sinks.logger-sink.channel = file-channel
testagent.sources.testlog.channels  = file-channel
```

Logs generated out of my test application should successfully be displayed into the flume agent log and events should be generated out of each log statement(line).

Answer (score 0):

Update the size of the event in the configuration as shown below:

```
testagent.sinks.logger-sink.maxBytesToLog = 256
```

The default size of the event is 16 bytes.